# Error when calling my function functionX : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'functionX' of null

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm working with Ionic3, I'm trying to integrate geolocation cordova source code in my file about.ts and I get a strange error:

When I call getMapLocation() from the html :

```
(click)="getMapLocation()"
```

This is the result:

```
core.js:1448 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'functionX' of null
    at webpackJsonp.195.AboutPage.onMapSuccess (about.ts:94)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4749)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runGuarded (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
```

Why I can't call "functionX" ?

## about.ts:

```
//Imports + Decorators
export class AboutPage{
//Constructor + some code

  getMapLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.onMapSuccess, this.onMapError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
    
  }

  onMapSuccess(position) {
    this.functionX();
    console.log(position);
    let Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    console.log('sss');
    let Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log('11');
    this.getMap(Latitude, Longitude);
    console.log('22');
  }  
  functionX(){
    console.log('functionX');
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context is incorrect, bind or pass a function to the first two `getCurrentPosition` arguments:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.onMapSuccess.bind(this), this.onMapError.bind(this), { enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

or

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(() => this.onMapSuccess(), () => this.onMapError(), { enableHighAccuracy: true });
```